Reservoir sampling vs Sampling excluding replacements
I am trying to understand the tradeoff between using Reservoir sampling Algorithm L and generating random values until I have enough unique values. This separates into finding the expected value for two random processes given the population size $N$ and the sample size $k$. I am assuming checking for duplicate results is significantly faster than generating a random value.
Naive sampling:
So I am looking to determine the expected number of uniform random integers $[0, N)$ that have $k$ unique values. Based on this Stats Exchange Post I have the expected number of samples to generate k unique values:
$$
E[\text{PRNG calls to generate }k\text{ unique values}]=\sum_{j=N-(k-1)}^N \frac{N}{j} = N(H_N - H_{N-k})
$$
Reservoir Sampling:
This is where I am having trouble. I would like to also find the expected number of PRNG calls for Algorithm L. Here is my understanding of Algorithm L:

Initialize the reservoir of size $k$ to the first $[0,k)$ values.

Use one call to the PRNG to sample the distribution of the $k^\text{th}$ order statistic of $k$ uniformly distributed $[0,1]$ random variables. This is the threshold $W$.

Initialize $i$ with $k$ and then, using the PRNG, sample a shifted geometric distribution parameterized by $W$ to add to the result.


While $i < N$:

Use the PRNG to sample a uniform integer distribution $[0,k)$ and assign the $i^\text{th}$ value to that index in the reservoir.

Update the threshold $W$ by using the PRNG to sample the distribution of the $k^\text{th}$ order statistic of $i$ uniformly distributed $[0,1]$ random variables. $W=W \exp{(\log{(u[0,1])}/k)}$

Increment $i$ by using the PRNG to sample a shifted geometric distribution parameterized by the updated $W$.


I get stuck on the updating threshold $W$. How do I find the expected value of how many times I need to increment $i$ and update $W$ for $i\ge{}N$?
